# Trying to use a JavaFX connect4 game with a server for school

Tags: javafx, multidimensional-array, logic

I have a leftover project from school that I could not get working as intended. The class had a Connect4 text game, then a GUI (using JavaFX), then a server-client for it.

My standalone GUI will go until the game is won by player, but it crashes at that point if green wins(Long error message but seems to end in IllegalArgumentException related to java's Parent class)

Also I don't know if it is plausible to do a JavaFX server interaction for this, or if I should scrap and do swing, but I really wanted to get this working for my peace of mind. Right now I am struggling with the idea of backend and GUI logic for winning, but it is the only design I could get working to this extent, poor design as it is...

Please let me know if more information is needed, I know this program is a mess as I have not done GUIs before and I am afraid to clean up the program before fixing it. The source file is long but the error seems to be related to an illegal argument exception with a Parent object.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    GridPane rectangleRoot = new GridPane();
    GridPane circleRoot = new GridPane();
    makeCircleBoard(rectangleRoot, circleRoot, playerColor);

    rectangleRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    circleRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Scene scene = new Scene(rectangleRoot, 1000, 1000);

    Rectangle gameBoardSpace = new Rectangle(scene.getWidth() / 2, scene.getHeight() 
 /2, Color.DARKBLUE);

    rectangleRoot.getChildren().add(gameBoardSpace);
    rectangleRoot.getChildren().add(circleRoot);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Connect4");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();

}

public GridPane makeCircleBoard(GridPane rectangleRoot, GridPane circleRoot, String colorPassed)
{
    int rowPerCol[] = new int[7];   //for back end 2D array
    int turn = 1;   //game logic


    for(int i = 0; i < ROWMAX; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLMAX; j++)
        {
            gridLayout[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    for(int row = 0; row < 6; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 7; col++)
        {
            GameSlot newCircle = new GameSlot(30, Color.WHITE);
            newCircle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
            newCircle.setStroke(Color.web("black", 1.0));
            newCircle.setStrokeWidth(4);
            newCircle.setLocationRow(row);
            newCircle.setLocationCol(col);
            newCircle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    if(newCircle.getOccupied() == false)
                    {
                        if(playerColor.equals("Yellow"))
                        {
                            gridLayout[newCircle.getLocationRow()][newCircle.getLocationCol()] = 'Y';
                            playerColor = "Green";
                            newCircle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                            newCircle.setOccupiedTrue();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gridLayout[newCircle.getLocationRow()][newCircle.getLocationCol()] = 'G';
                            playerColor = "Yellow";
                            newCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                            newCircle.setOccupiedTrue();
                        }

                    }

                    if(gameWon(gridLayout))
                    {
                        if(playerColor.equals("Green"))
                        {
                            final Text actiontarget = new Text();
                            actiontarget.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);;
                            actiontarget.setText("YELLOW WON!!!");
                            actiontarget.setScaleX(10);
                            actiontarget.setScaleY(10);
                            actiontarget.setTranslateX(rectangleRoot.getWidth() / 5);
                            rectangleRoot.getChildren().add(actiontarget);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            final Text actiontarget = new Text();
                            actiontarget.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);;
                            actiontarget.setText("GREEN WON!!!");
                            rectangleRoot.getChildren().add(actiontarget);
                            actiontarget.setScaleX(10);
                            actiontarget.setScaleY(10);
                            actiontarget.setTranslateX(rectangleRoot.getWidth() / 5);
                            rectangleRoot.getChildren().add(actiontarget);
                        }
                    }
                }   //end handle()

            });
                    //circle.setId(Integer.toString(i));
                    circleRoot.add(newCircle, row, col);



                    //newCircle.isWon(row, col);
        }

    }
```

The checks for Green and Yellow are the same. It checks the different directions for the color characters opposite of the color who is up next. I see no errors for Yellow in any win condition and they have the index checking in gridLayout2.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=CENTER
at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
at Connect4.ui.Connect4GUI$1.handle(Connect4GUI.java:128)
at Connect4.ui.Connect4GUI$1.handle(Connect4GUI.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is an `IllegalArgumentException` saying you are attempting to add a `Node` to the same `Parent` more than once—this is not allowed in JavaFX. If you look at the stack trace, you'll see where in your code this is happening.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=CENTER
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
    at Connect4.ui.Connect4GUI$1.handle(Connect4GUI.java:128)
    at Connect4.ui.Connect4GUI$1.handle(Connect4GUI.java:1)
```

The first frame that is not internal JavaFX code is `Connect4.ui.Connect4GUI$1.handle(Connect4GUI.java:128)` stating that the error is occurring on line `128` of your `Connect4GUI` class, inside a method named `handle`. You don't specify what line is line `128` but based on your code and the above information we know to focus on this part of your code:

```
newCircle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(newCircle.getOccupied() == false)
        {
            if(playerColor.equals("Yellow"))
            {
                gridLayout[newCircle.getLocationRow()][newCircle.getLocationCol()] = 'Y';
                playerColor = "Green";
                newCircle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                newCircle.setOccupiedTrue();
            }
            else
            {
                gridLayout[newCircle.getLocationRow()][newCircle.getLocationCol()] = 'G';
                playerColor = "Yellow";
                newCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                newCircle.setOccupiedTrue();
            }

        }

        if(gameWon(gridLayout))
        {
            if(playerColor.equals("Green"))
            {
                final Text actiontarget = new Text();
                actiontarget.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);;
                actiontarget.setText("YELLOW WON!!!");
                actiontarget.setScaleX(10);
                actiontarget.setScaleY(10);
                actiontarget.setTranslateX(rectangleRoot.getWidth() / 5);
                rectangleRoot.getChildren().add(actiontarget);

            }
            else
            {
                final Text actiontarget = new Text();
                actiontarget.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);;
                actiontarget.setText("GREEN WON!!!");
                rectangleRoot.getChildren().add(actiontarget);
                actiontarget.setScaleX(10);
                actiontarget.setScaleY(10);
                actiontarget.setTranslateX(rectangleRoot.getWidth() / 5);
                rectangleRoot.getChildren().add(actiontarget);
            }
        }
    }   //end handle()
});
```

Looking at the code, the issue can be located inside the `else` block that is within the `if(gameWon(gridLayout))` block:

```
else
{
    final Text actiontarget = new Text();
    actiontarget.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);;
    actiontarget.setText("GREEN WON!!!");
    rectangleRoot.getChildren().add(actiontarget); // DUPLICATE LINE BELOW
    actiontarget.setScaleX(10);
    actiontarget.setScaleY(10);
    actiontarget.setTranslateX(rectangleRoot.getWidth() / 5);
    rectangleRoot.getChildren().add(actiontarget); // DUPLICATE: Must be line 128
}
```

Remove one of those statements and the code should no longer throw the `IllegalArgumentException`. Notice that the stack trace points you right at the offending line of code, by the way.